# Python - Finding the average of scores of a list in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the average scores of a list in a list, using lambda.

```
Scores=[['James','Q',3,4,1,5],['Kat','S',3,4,1,2],['John','G',3,5,6,4]['Erikson','G',3,7,6,8],['Filip','NJ',3,8,9,9]]
sortedScores=sorted(Scores,key=lambda score:avg(score[3:],reverse=False))

for i in Scores:
    print(i[0:1],avg(i[3:]))
```

`avg` is not a command, so what would be the best way to calculate the average within this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a comma, that's all:

```
Scores=[
    ['James','Q',3,4,1,5],
    ['Ryan','G',3,4,1,2],
    ['Klodiano','G',3,5,6,4]['Erikson','G',3,7,6,8],
    #                      ^^
    ['Filip','NJ',3,8,9,9]
]
```

Without the comma, the list `['Klodiano','G',3,5,6,4]` is being indexed, but instead of an integer, you passed in the tuple `('Erikson','G',3,7,6,8)`.

Note that your `sorted()` list also has an error:

```
sortedScores=sorted(
    Scores,
    key=lambda score:avg(score[3:],reverse=False))
    #                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are passing in the `reverse=False` to the `avg()` callable, not to `sorted()`. You probably wanted:

```
sortedScores=sorted(
    Scores,
    key=lambda score:avg(score[3:]),
    reverse=False)
```

instead.

You don't need to slice if you wanted to print the name of each student separately; you'd use indexing instead:

```
for i in Scores:
    print(i[0], avg(i[3:]))
```

And finally, the  [GCSE programming problem](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gawvg/gcse_computing_programming_tasks_14_16_year_olds/) you are implementing asks for the last 3 scores, not for all scores except the first 1. You need to use `-3` to slice of the last 3 scores to calculate the average:

```
avg(score[-3:])
```

Comment: Thank you. Silly of me not to notice!